# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to connect my Redux store to my React project, but I keep getting this error:

> ../node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js Module not
>   found: Can't resolve 'react' in
>   'C:\Users.\Documents..\node_modules\react-redux\es\components'

I've installed both `react-redux` and `redux` (I believe react-redux has some dependencies on redux)

```
import { Provider} from 'react-redux';
```

This is what is giving the error.

Any suggestions on what I could do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be caused by your `node_modules`

First delete your node_modules, package-lock.json, and yarn.lock then install all dependencies again

like
`rm -rf node_modules`
`rm -rf package-lock.json`
`rm -rf yarn.lock`

then run

`npm install` or `yarn install`

Comment: ISN'T JAVASCRIPT GREAT!?

Answer (score 3):

> Please import react at top

`import React from 'react`'

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue and it seems you installed react-redux first and redux later.

I assume, react-redux is having some dependencies on redux, which might have created this error. So, recommending you to delete the package-lock.json , run npm install and then npm start.

Let me know if this works!

Thanks

Comment: Can you give me ur package.json? I want to see the version of both redux and react-redux

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, Just run `npm audit fix` to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a left-field answer, but turns out I'd configured `react` and `react-dom` as `peerDependencies` in my package.json. Moving them into regular `dependencies` did the trick.

(This is a common webpack error message, so anything building with webpack that expects a module it can't find will blow up with this same error).