# AppLoading errors/issues for expo

Tags: react-native, expo

SDK version: 44

My problem seems to be that I’m unable to install `AppLoading` on Expo.
Looking inside the `package.json` dependencies, I’m not able to find `expo-app-loading`
It says I have to install it manually by typing: `expo install expo-app-loading` in the terminal. I've tried doing so but nothing changes and I still can't see `expo-app-loading` installed in `package.json` dependencies.

As soon as I `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';` I get bombarded by errors that I've copy/pasted below:

Any help on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

````
1 | import React from ‘react’;
2 |
3 | import { AppLoadingProps } from ‘./AppLoading.types’;
4 | import NativeAppLoading from ‘./AppLoadingNativeWrapper’;
…/…/…/…/…/node_modules/expo-app-loading/build/AppLoadingNativeWrapper.js:2
Module not found: Can’t resolve ‘react’
1 | import * as SplashScreen from ‘expo-splash-screen’;
2 | import React from ‘react’;
3 |
4 | type Props = {
5 | autoHideSplash?: boolean;
…/…/…/…/…/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/PermissionsHook.js:1
Module not found: Can’t resolve ‘react’
1 | import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from ‘react’;
2 |
3 | import { PermissionResponse } from ‘./PermissionsInterface’;
4 |
C:/Users/Admin/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘react-native-web/dist/exports/DeviceEventEmitter’ in ‘C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build’
C:/Users/Admin/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/EventEmitter.js
Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘react-native-web/dist/exports/NativeEventEmitter’ in ‘C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build’
C:/Users/Admin/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/Platform.js
Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform’ in ‘C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build’
C:/Users/Admin/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/EventEmitter.js
Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform’ in ‘C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\expo-modules-core\build’
…/…/…/…/…/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/SyntheticPlatformEmitter.web.js:5
Module not found: Can’t resolve ‘react-native-web/dist/vendor/react-native/NativeEventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter’
3 | * registered in the API layer with NativeEventEmitter.
4 | */
5 | export { default } from ‘react-native-web/dist/vendor/react-native/NativeEventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter’;
6 |
Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat ‘C:\DumpStack.log.tmp’```
````

Comment: you missed the import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

Comment: Yes I've tried installing it manually by typing ```expo install expo-app-loading``` and nothing changes.

Comment: no, you dont import it at top of your code! paste `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';` to line 2 in your code

Comment: I've also imported the package at the top of my component ```import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';``` That's when I get bombarded by the errors I've posted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740483/module-not-found-cant-resolve-react)

Comment: Unfortunately no, once I deleted & reinstalled everything I got this message in the terminal: ```Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.```